# Python's join() won't join the string representation (__str__) of my object

Tags: python

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here:

```
>>> class Stringy(object):
...     def __str__(self):
...             return "taco"
...     def __repr__(self):
...             return "taco"
... 
>>> lunch = Stringy()
>>> lunch
taco
>>> str(lunch)
'taco'
>>> '-'.join(('carnitas',lunch))
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: sequence item 1: expected string, Stringy found
```

Given my inclusion of the `__str__()` method in the Stringy object, shouldn't `join()` see lunch as a string?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`''.join` does not call `__str__` on the items of the sequence it's joining.  **Every** object has a `__str__`, after all (be it only inherited from `object`), therefore if `join` worked that way it would join up **any** sequence whatsoever (after stringification) -- often to weird effects.  Better to have the the user call up `str` explicitly when warranted ("explicit is better than implicit" being one of the mottos in "The Zen of Python", after all).

You could subclass `str` or `unicode` if you want to "be" a string.  Otherwise, an explicit `str` call will be needed to make instances of your type "become" strings.

Answer (score 14):

no you have to convert it to str yourself

```
'-'.join(('carnitas',str(lunch)))
```

if you have to do it for a whole sequence of items

```
'-'.join(str(x) for x in seq)
```

or

```
'-'.join(map(str, seq))
```

for your particular case you can just write

```
'carnitas-'+str(lunch)
```

Comment: +1 for correct answer *and* using generator expression instead of the horrible "let's create another list because we barely know list comprehension" :)

Answer (score 1):

The call signature for `str.join` is:

```
S.join(sequence) -> string

Return a string which is the concatenation of the strings in the
sequence.  The separator between elements is S.
```

Notice that `sequence` is expected to be a sequence of strings. Lots of objects have `__str__` methods, but not all of them (like `Stringy`) is an instance of `str`.

The fix, of course, is simple:

```
'-'.join(('carnitas',str(lunch)))
```