# Why I can't use join for a list of objects that implement __str__?

Tags: python, duck-typing

I am studying duck typing in Python,I know that if you implement some special methods for a class, you can happily use the built-in class methods

for example:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self,l):
        self._l = l
    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self._l)
```

If I do this ,I can use `for...in..,zip`, and some other methods that is built in and also can do some other stuffs, like implement  `__setitem__()` ,so I can use random.choice,random.shuffle,and I feel python is so cool,but then I find this problem,I want to use join to print some objects that I implemented their `__str__` methods,but it won't work

I find that this is because when we use join,we write it like `';'.join(l)`,so the duck typing trick won't work for it,because it use str's methods rather than the objects will be joined

## But why?since many build in methods designed to friendly to duck typing,why not 'join'?

@SethMMorton is point my doubts,thank you
I know I can use `';'.join([str(i) for i in l])` to solve my problem,but I don't know why python don't do it itself?

Comment: Does your custom sequence type contain numbers? You will also get an error if you try to join a sequence type that contains numbers. For example: `';'.join(range(3))` throws `TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, int found`.

Comment: `join` *does* use duck typing. You can pass it any interable (such as you `A` class) that contains strings and it will insert the string between each element.

Comment: This question is really "why doesn't join automatically call `str` on each element of the given iterable?", correct?  If so, this is a good question but the way it is currently worded makes it difficult to see that. I recommend cleaning up the wording to make your point more clear.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python's join() won't join the string representation (\_\_str\_\_) of my object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3410647/pythons-join-wont-join-the-string-representation-str-of-my-object)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Answering the "why": Everything in Python is convertible to `str`, as even without `__str__`, the `repr` of the object is used when a `str` form is requested. Python may be flexible, but what you're describing is weak typing (which Python doesn't do in general), not duck typing. The presence of `__str__` means you can *coerce* to a string, but it doesn't mean "is a string".

Allowing arbitrary iterables to be iterated with `for` loops, `zip`, etc. isn't weak typing, because it's a common interface with no ambiguity; iterables iterate the same way, even if they might produce different types.

Actual weak typing is dangerous, because it can allow errors to pass silently. It's particularly noticeable in Python 3. If automatic coercion to `str` was allowed, and you did:

```
iterable_of_bytes_objects = b'123', b'456'

','.join(iterable_of_bytes_objects)
```

You'd silently produce `"b'123',b'456'"`, when odds are, you just forgot the leading `b` on the join string, and meant:

```
b','.join(iterable_of_bytes_objects)
```

Or maybe you meant to produce a string but forgot to `decode` the `bytes`. Or maybe you wanted the `repr` of each object, or the `str`, or whatever. Python has no idea, and per the Zen of Python (`import this`):

> In the face of ambiguity, refuse the temptation to guess.

as well as:

> Explicit is better than implicit.

Coercing automatically hides errors and involves heuristic guesswork about what people "probably want". If you want to coerce, that's what `','.join(map(str, iterable))` is for, but it means you opted in to a specific form of coercion, and it's assumed you know what you're doing, which matches the other Zen requirements:

> Errors should never pass silently.
>
> Unless explicitly silenced.

Comment: thank you,I think this is the answer I need,
have a __str__don't mean a str,and the difference of duck typing and weak typing
I see it now,thank you again

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a problem with duck-typing. It's a problem with the items contained in your custom series class. You will get the same error if you try to join a numeric `range()`. Instead do this:

```
';'.join(str(i) for i in l)
```

This is explained clearly in the documentation for [`string.join(iterable)`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#str.join): "Return a string which is the concatenation of the strings in the iterable *iterable*."

Comment: For those into a more functional approach, `';'.join(map(str, l))` can be used.

Comment: @SethMMorton: While `map(str, l)` is more succinct and slightly faster, it is not "more functional" (and the speed gain is a quirk of the interpreter, it might not hold outside CPython). Generator expressions are functional too; they (along with the similar list comprehensions) are borrowed from Haskell, which is a pure functional language. They are 100% functional constructs.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Would a better phrasing have been "if you don't like creating a dummy looping variable...", or "if you prefer functions to generator expressions..."?  I wasn't trying to be pedantic, and also note that nowhere did I claim the original solution is *not* functional.

Comment: @SethMMorton: You did claim `map` was _more_ functional though, which is incorrect. It's just as functional as listcomp/genexpr (they're all intended for applying a side-effect free transform of the input iterable to a new output iterable). The tendency of people to call `map` "more functional" when it isn't is a pedantic bugaboo of mine, sorry. Anyway, as for what to call it, more succinct is obviously true, as is avoiding looping variables, and as I noted, `map` with a C implemented built-in function is going to be faster on CPython, so selling it on any of those points is reasonable.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Not my intent. I intended it to be read as "Here's an alternate approach using a function as opposed to a generator expression", not "Here's a solution that more strictly adheres to a functional paradigm since this solution clearly does not". It's too bad inflection is lost in text.